# C# Silverlight WCF Linq Service Select from MSQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, linq, silverlight

I am having a horrid time with this, I have an assignment and cannot figure out how to work the silverlight WCF Linq services.  I have values from a Locations table binding to a combo box okay, so the cities are displayed properly.  On the SelectionChanged event I want to pass the location_name to a GetWeather() function and display the related weather from another table.  I can't firgure out how to use the location_name to select the related P_id, which is in the weather table as location_id and then display the Weather from the related location_id.

This is the code i have so far... but it is not working...  I am just hoping its simple, because c# isnt my bag at all.

my ServiceReference file for the GetWeather() function is

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetWeather(string location_name)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext a = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    var identity = (from o in a.locations
                    where o.location_name == location_name
                    select o.P_Id);
    var weatherType = (from o in a.weathers
                       where o.location_id.Equals(identity)
                       select o.weather).ToString();

    return weatherType;
}
```

and the code in the main C# page is here... what am i doing wrong...

```
private void location_cmb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    a.GetWeatherCompleted += new EventHandler<GetWeatherCompletedEventArgs>(a_GetWeatherCompleted);
    a.GetWeatherAsync(location_cmb.SelectedItem.ToString());
}

void a_GetWeatherCompleted(object sender, GetWeatherCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textBlock2.Text = e.Result;
}
```

Visual Studio is not showing any errors but it is not running still... I am out of ideas

Comment: Linq always returns a collection;To get top 1, check if the returned value is null, then get first item in it. In your case, first select will return a IEnumerable, it couldn't be equaled to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is it, but some things I have noticed:

This code:

```
(from o in a.locations where o.location_name == location_name select o.P_Id)
```

Actually returns a [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx), not a single item so it's probably not working correctly when you try to use it in:

```
(from o in a.weathers where o.location_id.Equals(identity) select o.weather)
```

In order to indicate that you only want one element returned from your query, you can use the [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx), [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx), [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) or [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) methods.

For example:

```
var identity = (from o in a.locations where o.location_name == location_name select o.P_Id).Single();
```

I would have a quick read on each of the methods (First, FirstOrDefault etc) to see which one is appropriate for your use case but if you are sure you will get 1 result (i.e. location_name is unique in your database) then using Single() should be OK.

This gets you the `identity` (which I assume is an integer type) and you can use this in your following query:

```
var weatherType = (from o in a.weathers where o.location_id == identity select o.weather).Single();
```

To get a single record out...I am assuming here that o.weather (i.e. the `weather` attribute in your class/column in your database) is a string and that you only want/expect a single record.

Perhaps give that a try?

---

**PS.** Reading your queries in the `GetWeather()` method, I think it might also be possible to combine your two queries into a single call...but I think perhaps we should get the base working and then go from there (following the "make it work, make it better" mantra).

**PPS.** With your `DataContext`, you should probably consider wrapping it in a `using` statement or otherwise [disposing](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2625b105-2cff-45ad-ba29-abdd763f74fe/) of it once you've finished working with it.

---

I'm not going to do a good job of this, but here is (from my limited understanding) the key differentiators between those `First`, `SingleOrDefault` methods listed higher above in this response:

- `First` returns the first item in the collection or throws an Exception if the collection is empty (zero elements)
- `FirstOrDefault` returns the first item in the collection or null if the collection empty (zero elements)
- `Single` returns the only item in the collection or throws an Exception if the collection does not have exactly one item
- `SingleOrDefault` returns the first item in the collection, null if the collection is empty (zero elements) and throws an exception if the collection has more than 1 element

Comment: Don't forget to check null before calling single:)